# Testing multiple string 'in' conditions in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, multiple-conditions

I am trying to add multiple 'or' clauses to a python if statement using list comprehension. My code is shown below. I would like to keep the list comprehension. In terms of pseudocode, the logic would simply be:

Alive_Beatles = each name that contains '(Beatle)' **and** either ('Paul', 'Yoko' or 'Ringo')

The code only returns Paul and skips Ringo and Yoko.

```
Names = ["John Lennon (Beatle)",  "Paul McCartney (Beatle)", "Ringo Starr (Beatle)", "Yoko Ono (Beatle)", "Mick Jagger (Rolling Stone)", "Brian Jones (Rolling Stone)", "Alex Jones (na)", "Adam Smith (na)"]
Alive_Beatles = [n for n in Names if ("Beatle" and ("Paul" or "Ringo" or "Yoko")) in n]

print Alive_Beatles
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value

Comment: Closed as dupe, reopened because of the second question, wish I had not reopened. Need coffee.

Comment: @timgeb Cheers, go get your coffee.

Comment: The title of this question is very misleading, esp. given that it was closed in favor of something non-list-comprehension-related. What to do?

Comment: I fixed the title to reflect the actual question. I guess we can leave it closed, although I don't think it's an exact dupe and the answers here are better.

Answer (score 3):

You need to test each name explicitly if it's `in n`:

```
[n for n in Names if ("Beatle" in n and ("Paul" in n or "Ringo" in n or "Yoko" in n))]
```

Otherwise the `and` and `or` use the truth value of you search strings (and each non-empty string is always True) and finally tests if `Paul in n` (the first truth value of the `or`s).

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) explicitly mentions this:

> ### 4.2. Boolean Operations — and, or, not
>
> These are the Boolean operations, ordered by ascending priority:
>
> ```
> Operation     Result                                Notes
> x or y        if x is false, then y, else x         (1)
> x and y       if x is false, then x, else y         (2)
> not x         if x is false, then True, else False  (3)
> ```
>
> #### Notes:
>
> (1) This is a short-circuit operator, so it only evaluates the second argument if the first one is false.
>
> (2) This is a short-circuit operator, so it only evaluates the second argument if the first one is true.
>
> (3) not has a lower priority than non-Boolean operators, so not a == b is interpreted as not (a == b), and a == not b is a syntax error.

So `"Beatle" and (...)` evaluates according to (2) to the second argument because `"Beatle"` is truthy and according to (1) it evaluates to the first argument of the chained `or`s: `"Paul"` because it's also truthy.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't do what you expect because the expression

```
("Paul" or "Ringo" or "Yoko")
```

evaluates to `"Paul"`. Type it in at an interpreter prompt to confirm this.

And even that only seems to work because

```
("Beatle" and ("Paul" or "Ringo" or "Yoko"))
```

also evaluates to `"Paul"`.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward solution is to just list

```
[n for n in Names if "Beatle" in n and ("Paul" in n or "Ringo" in n or "Yoko" in n)]
```

But you could use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to get a bit closer to what you tried initially:

```
[n for n in Names if "Beatle" in n and any(x in n for x in ("Paul", "Ringo", "Yoko"))]
```